# Not able to extract Json Data in Apache-NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have written a below POST command and using "**HandleHttpRequest**" processor to receive the POST request in Apache NiFi

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"employeeDetails":{"empid":"124","empname": "praveen"}}' http://localhost:7002
```

I am able to receive the json data in "handleHttpRequest" processor as shown below

[image]

when I check the list queue I am able to see the json data

[image]

HandleHttpProcessor details

[image]

But I want to extract empid and check whether empid of my json data is null or not,I tried 
"**ExtractText**","**ReplaceText**","**UpdateAttribute**","**EvaluateJsonPath**" etc **Processors** to fetch empolyee details but I am unable to do it.

EvaluateJson path details

[image]

I am getting "flowfile **did not have a valid JSON content**"  error in EvaluateJsonPath processor

How do I extract empdata and check whether its null or not?

Comment: Would you please post your EvaluateJsonPath configuration?

Comment: I tried "EvaluateJsonPath" ,but it is mainly used when we pull a json file from certain location right? before that I am trying the splitjson processor, I am getting invalid json format error.. but my goal is to extract json data from Post Request(the json data is already available in queue).

Comment: For debugging my Json, i saved my "test files" on a repository with ```PutFile``` processor. Especially for Json, I used [this tool](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to help me!

Comment: I used Postman instead of CURL command,I was able to retrieve the required fields

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to NiFi. You should post data with CURL like this (change double quote `"` to single quote `'` after `-d`):

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"employeeDetails":{"empid":"124","empname": "praveen"}}' http://localhost:7002
```

Comment: appreciate your comment..but still I am getting "did not have a valid json content" error..even though my json content is valid..added the details to question

Comment: Oh, your problem with json is related to double quotes, your received data is not a valid json, is should be some thing like this: `{"employeeDetails":{"empid":"124","empname": "praveen"}}`

Comment: I used your same curl command, in the list queue  my json is appended with single quotes (')   as shown below                                                 '{employeeDetails:{empid:124,empname:praveen}}'                                                                       Hence again I am getting the "not a valid json " content in NiFi

Comment: I used Postman instead of CURL command,I was able to retrieve the required fields.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same two processors you have, additionally, I also have a HandleHTTPResponse added so that my curl command exits neatly without sending additional buffer messages that make the EvaluateJSONPath component fail with invalid JSON error (My guess is this could have been your case as well).
[HTTP Request Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Non.png)

Also as @Behrouz Seyedi mentioned you would need to use a single quote in your command. This is my curl command

```sh
curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"employeeDetails":{"empid":"124","empname": "praveen"}}' http://localhost:7003
```

This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I61qF.png) to the EvaluateJSONPath processor.

This is the response of the EvaluateJSONPath
[empid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFHLK.png)

Comment: can you share your EvaluatejsonPath configuration?

Comment: updated the answer with the configuration for EvaluatejsonPath